# Porque o CakePHP seta o _method igual a PUT ao invés de POST?

Tags: php, cakephp

Atualizei recentemente meu projeto CakePHP para a versão 2.4.5.

Desde então, alguns dos meus formulários, estão com o `input hidden _method` setado como PUT automaticamente. A única maneira de contornar isso, é setando o `'type' => 'POST'`.

Porém, isso não era precisa antigamente. Não sei se estou fazendo algo errado, ou se é um BUG.

#### Esse é o formulário

```php
  <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('action' => 'new_password', $this->request->data['User']['forget_password'], 'admin' => false), 'autocomplete' => 'off')) ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('User.id') ?>

    <fieldset>
      <label class="block clearfix">
        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
          <?php echo $this->Form->password('User.password', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Digite a nova senha')) ?>
          <i class="icon-user"></i>
        </span>
      </label>

      <label class="block clearfix">
        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
          <?php echo $this->Form->password('User.password_confirmation', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Digite novamente a nova senha')) ?>
          <i class="icon-user"></i>
        </span>
      </label>

      <div class="space"></div>

      <div class="clearfix">
        <?php echo $this->Form->button('<i class="icon-key"></i> '. __('Enviar'), array('class' => 'width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-success', 'escape' => false)) ?>
      </div>

      <div class="space-4"></div>
    </fieldset>
  <?php echo $this->Form->end() ?>
```

#### E essa é a action:

```php
/**
 * new_password method
 *
 * @access public
 * @param String $forget_password
 * @return void
 * @since 1.0 
 * @version 1.0 
 * @author Patrick Maciel
 */
public function new_password($forget_password)
{

  $user = $this->User->findByForgetPassword($forget_password);

  if ($user == false) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Link inválido'), 'flash/frontend/error');
    $this->redirect('/');
  }

  $this->layout = 'login';

  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->User->set = $this->request->data;
    if ($this->User->validates(array('fieldList' => array('id', 'forget_password', 'password', 'password_confirmation')))) {

     // ...

    } else {

     // ...

    }
  }

  $user['User']['password'] = null;
  $this->request->data = $user;

}
```

**Obs.: Eu não setei o **type*** do formulário acima, justamente para testar se o mesmo iria ocorrer, e o ocorreu.*

Comment: A action (e rota) da página com o formulário é a mesma do target?

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim. Assim como apresentado acima.

Comment: Eu estava desconfiando das [rotas padrão de REST](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html#modifying-the-default-rest-routes), ms parece que não é isso...

Comment: @bfavaretto Creio que seja isso, porém ainda não entendi como o CakePHP trata isso. Veja minha resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que eu vi o que acontece é que se tu tens um registro selecionado ele considera o método PUT como padrão, caso tu não tenha um registro ativo ele coloca como POST.

Podemos ver isso aqui:

```php
if ($model !== false && $key) {
      $recordExists = (
          isset($this->request->data[$model]) &&
          !empty($this->request->data[$model][$key]) &&
          !is_array($this->request->data[$model][$key])
       );

      if ($recordExists) {
          $created = true;
          $id = $this->request->data[$model][$key];
      }
}
```

Depois vemos isto:

```php
'type' => ($created && empty($options['action'])) ? 'put' : 'post',
```

Então pelo que entendi se tu utilizar um formulário que seja de criação e que tu não esteja recuperando dados do model ele vai fazer um POST.

Fonte: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php

Comment: Excelente observação. Então é por isso que está considerando um PUT, pois eu busco as informações do usuário, antes de prosseguir. Obrigado.

Comment: é a lógica deles é que se você tem um registro ativo então tu quer atualizar, vai dar certo na maioria dos casos, menos nesse teu caso, mas mesmo assim o CAKE ta certo, tu vai atualizar o registro então deveria ser um PUT mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Ainda não sei qual a lógica por trás do CakePHP para fazer isso mas é o seguinte:

Se a action não for `add()`, ele considera como `PUT`, ao menos que a action seja `delete`.

Sendo assim, caso seja um rota qualquer customizada, fugindo do padrão REST, você deve setar manualmente:

```php
'type' => 'POST'
```

E pronto.

---

**Obs.:** testei tanto remover o `User.id`, quanto remover os parâmetros da `url` do Form, mas mesmo assim ele manteve como PUT

Referência: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-forms

Answer (score 0):

Ao usar `put` ou `delete`, o form será `post`, mas quando submetido, o método de solicitação HTTP será substituído por `PUT` ou `DELETE`, respectivamente. Isto permite o CakePHP emular o suporte REST em navegadores web.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create

Answer (score 0):

O CakePHP usa `POST` no formulário e seta o atributo `_method` como `PUT` porque o método `PUT`, em geral, não é nativamente suportado pelos navegadores.

O framework Symfony2 faz a mesma coisa, e veja o que eles dizem na documentação:

> Unfortunately, life isn't quite this simple, since most browsers do not support sending PUT and DELETE requests. Fortunately Symfony2 provides you with a simple way of working around this limitation. By including a _method parameter in the query string or parameters of an HTTP request, Symfony2 will use this as the method when matching routes. Forms automatically include a hidden field for this parameter if their submission method is not GET or POST.

Fonte: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html